# Isotropy group of connection is isomorphic to centraliser of holonomy group

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

I am asking for a proof of Lemma (4.2.8) of *Donaldson, Kronheimer: The Geometry of Four-Manifolds*.

Let $P \rightarrow X$ be a principal bundle with structure group $G$.
Denote by $\mathcal{G}$ the gauge group.
Let $A$ be a connection on $P$ and $H_A \subset G$ its holonomy.
Denote by
$$
\Gamma_A=
\{u \in \mathcal{G} | u(A)=A \}
$$
the isotropy group of $A$ in $\mathcal{G}$.
Then the claim of the lemma is:

> For any connection $A$ over a connected base $X$, $\Gamma_A$ is isomorphic to the centraliser of $H_A$ in $G$.

My attempt to prove it:
Now if the bundle was trivial, i.e. $P=X \times G$, we could take $g \in G$ in the centraliser of $H_A$ and get a unique element $u_g \in \mathcal{G}$ satisfying $u_g(x,e)=(x,g)$.
If the connection $A$ is the trivial connection then it is easy to check that this satisfies $u_g \in \Gamma_A$.

In matrix notation we have $u(A)=u^{-1}Au+u^{-1} du$.
Plugging in an $A$-horizontal vector field to this formula shows that any $u \in \Gamma_A$ needs to be constant on $X \times \{e\}$, i.e. $u=u_g$ for some $g \in G$.
Plugging in a vertical vector field shows that $g$ must be in the centraliser of $H_A$ in $G$, because $u^{-1} du$ vanishes on vertical vector fields.

I believe I can make this argument work for non-trivial connections $A$.
But no matter if I can or cannot: all of this assumed that the bundle was trivial.
If the bundle isn't trivial I don't even know how to write down a map from the centraliser of $H_A$ to $\Gamma_A$.

Comment: I think you want $A$ to be a $G$-connection not just any connection.

Comment: That's right. I copied the wording from the book. In the book it is clear from the context that I am asking for $A$ to be what I'd call a "principal bundle connection", which should be the same as your $G$-connection. But I didn't provide that context here.

Comment: A proof sketch is given in "Tim Perutz: Smooth four-manifolds", where the statement has the name "Lemma 39". At the time of writing the comment, the text by Tim Perutz was available under this link: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/perutz/PDF_files/Smooth4manifolds.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix some $x\in X$ (and assume $X$ is connected).

There is an evaluation map $$\operatorname{ev}_x\colon\Gamma_A\to\operatorname{Aut}P_x=G.$$
The crucial property that we will exploit is:

> Any path $\gamma$ joining $x$ to $x'$ in $X$ gives an isomorphism between the $\operatorname{ev}_x(\Gamma_A)$ and $\operatorname{ev}_{x'}(\Gamma_A)$ (conjugation by the parallel transport along $\gamma$)

This gives us:

- $\operatorname{ev}_x$ is injective.
- When $\gamma$ runs through loops at $x$, we get $\operatorname{ev}_x(\Gamma_A)\subseteq C_G(H_A)$.

Conversely, given any $g\in C_G(H_A)$, we can define $u\in\mathcal{G}$ by:

- $u(x):=g$
- for any $x'\neq x$, let $\gamma$ be a path joining $x$ to $x'$, and
  $$
  u(x'):=(\Pi_\gamma)g(\Pi_\gamma)^{-1}
  $$
  where $\Pi_\gamma$ is the map "parallel transport along $\gamma$".  The condition $g\in C_G(H_A)$ ensures $(\Pi_\gamma)g(\Pi_\gamma)^{-1}$ does not depend on the choice of $\gamma$.  It is easy to check the horizontal subspace at $x$ (and hence at all other $x'$) is preserved by $u$, so $u\in\Gamma_A$.

It is clear the constructions are inverse of each other, so $\Gamma_A\cong C_G(H_A)$.

Comment: You write $\text{Aut} P_x=G$. What is that identification? I don't see a canonical one. You can fix an identification for one $x$ which explains how to go from $\Gamma_A$ to $C_G(H_A)$. But for the converse direction you seem to use that you have such an identification for all $x' \neq x$.

Comment: We have a (non-canonical) identification $G$ with $\operatorname{Aut}P_x$ for every $x$.  Yes technically everything should have $G$ replaced by $\operatorname{Aut} P_x$ (or $\operatorname{Aut}P_{x'}$ as appropriate), including the $H_A\subset G$ and the $G$ in $C_G$, so what we have is $\Gamma_A\cong C_{\operatorname{Aut}P_x}(H_{A,x})$.

Comment: I understand now and your solution makes perfect sense. Thank you!